# Queries is not working struts2

Tags: struts2

It works on struts2 but the data will not be updated in database it will retruned to the original data.The ddatabase connection is correct only it show the error in public string update() method.
 package mypack;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange.Map;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private int id;
    SessionMap<String,String> sessionmap;  



    public int getId1() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId1(int string) {
        this.id=string;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
     public String Register()
     {
     int i=UserDAO.insertData(this);  
        if(i>0){
        return "success";
     }

        return "error";  
     }  


    public String Login() throws ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        setName(req.getParameter("name"));
        setPassword(req.getParameter("pass"));
         if(LoginDAO.chechLogin(getName(),getPassword())){  
                return "success";  
            }  
            else{  
                return "error";  
            }  
    }

public String Update() throws Exception {

HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
setName(req.getParameter("name"));
setPassword(req.getParameter("password"));
setPassword(req.getParameter("email"));
setPassword(req.getParameter("phone"));




LoginAction user = null;
if (LoginDAO.updateData(user))
{
return "success";
}
else
return "error";
}
}

    /*public void setSession(Map map) {  
        sessionmap=(SessionMap)map;  
        sessionmap.put("Login","true");  
    } 
     public String Update(){

         UserDAO.updateData(this);  

            return "success";  


        }     
}
    /*  public String Login(){

            if(UserDAO.chech1Login(name,password)){  
                    return "success";  
                }  
                else{  
                    return "error";  
                }  
        }

/public String Delete(){

LoginAction user = null;
if(UserDAO.deleteData(user)){

                    return "success";  

    }
   else
         return "error";
         }
}
}*/
```

Comment: Unreadable. Post only relevant code. You don't need `req.getParameter`, getter/setter for property is enough.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **Update()** method. Before updating **user** you are setting it to **null**.

Comment: You are passing <b>null</p> reference in <b>updateData()</b> method of <b>LoginDAO</b> class.

Comment: Every thing is correct but the data will not be updated

Comment: I didn't get no error but the data will not be updated in the database

Comment: Can you share LoginDao and LoginAction classes?